# This is a seal on a porcelain piece. I am not sure if it is from China or Japan. Can anyone tell me what it says? (Characters identified: 大明嘉靖年製)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

I am trying to read the seal script on the base of a porcelain piece. I am not sure if it is from China or from Japan.

Comment: I see you have updated your subject title to include the answer provided by L Parker. Unless you are waiting for more responses, you shall accept his answer, and give him the credit. I don't think he cares, but it is a polite thing for you to do.

Comment: @r13 no, I did that. We've generally done this in Chinese StackExchange to make sure that it is easier to find past Q/As on [tag:character-identification] questions. For these Q/As to remain useful for Chinese SE, they need to be found easily & quickly.

Comment: @dROOOze I see.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

1. From right to left, up to down:

> 大明嘉靖年製
>
> Made during the Jiajing era of Great Ming

2. `大明` is the official name of the Ming dynasty. `嘉靖年` refers to the Jiajing era (1521–67). `製` is a verb meaning 'to make', here it is passive. So assuming this not being a counterfeit, it is from China.
3. An old character for `明` is `朙` (seen here), which is frequently adopted in seal scripts.